# Ошибка Null Pointer Exception в Java

Tags: java

При решении задачи возникает ошибка:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не правильно и как это исправить?

```
class Plural
{
    int [] Array;
    int level=5; 
    int k;
    public  Plural ()
    {
        int [] Array = new int[k];
    }
    void funct(int k)
    {
        if (k != 0 && level > 0)
        {

            Array[k] = 0;
            level=level-1;
            funct(k - 1);
            Array[k] = 1;
            level=level-1;
            funct(k - 1);

        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <5; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(Array[i] + ' ');
            }
        }
    }
}
class Inter
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Plural obj1=new Plural();
        obj1.funct(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: В полном тексте ошибки написано в какой строке происходит исключение.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Plural.funct(Inter.java:15)
 at Inter.main(Inter.java:37)

Comment: @lDrakonl присвоил,не помогает

Comment: Как написали ранее, у вас в ошибке указана строка, в которой вываливается исключение. Так же в вашей IDE должен быть дебагер. Сейчас самое время для того, чтобы с ним познакомиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Plural
{
    int level=5; // уровни рекурсии
    int k;
    int [] Array;
    public  Plural (int k)
    {
        this.k = k;
        Array = new int[k];
    }
    void funct()
    {
        if (k != 0 && level > 0)
        {
            Array[k-1] = 0;
            level=level-1;
            funct(k - 1);
            Array[k-1] = 1;
            level=level-1;
            funct(k - 1);

        }
        else
        {
            for (int number: Array)
            {
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }
    }

    void funct(int k)
    {
        if (k != 0 && level > 0)
        {

            Array[k-1] = 0;
            level=level-1;
            funct(k - 1);
            Array[k-1] = 1;
            level=level-1;
            funct(k - 1);

        }
        else
        {
            for (int number: Array)
            {
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }
    }
}
class Inter
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Plural obj1=new Plural(5);
        obj1.funct();
    }
}
```

- Инициализируйте массив в конструкторе, а не создавайте
  новый.
- Логичнее передавать в конструктор переменную k. Перегрузите
  функцию `funct`, чтобы в первый раз она работала не принимая
  аргументы, а все последующие рекурсивные вызовы принимала `k-1`.
  Тогда в `main` вы сможете один раз передать `k` в конструктор и
  вызвать `funct` без аргументов.
- У вас массив размера `k`, его последний элемент `k-1`,
  так что обращение к `k`-му элементу вызовет выход за границы массива.
  Вместо этого обращайтесь к `k-1` элементу.
- `System.out.println(Array[i] + ' ')` здесь вы прибавляете char к числу. 
  Char конвертируется в число (ASCII код), прибавляется к элементу массива 
  и выводится. Исправить это можно приведением элемента массива к строке.
  Хотя вам вовсе не обязательно прибавлять пробел к строке, вывод каждый 
  раз идет с новой строки.
- Для вывода массива лучше использовать цикл for each.

[Здесь можно протестировать код написанный мною](https://ideone.com/TtZWvO).

Comment: Спасибо большое, все понятно, но у меня видимо сам код написан не верно по скольку в вашем примере выводятся не те числа

Comment: @Pretty_Duck эту ошибку я тоже исправил

Comment: @ Звягинцев Денис Дико извиняюсь за простые для ошибки я только начал осваивать программирование спасибо что относитесь с пониманием и помогаете

Comment: @Pretty_Duck если все правильно работает, отметьте ответ как правильный

Comment: Вроде бы да) надо еще в Arrays.toString перевести для наглядности

Answer (score 1):

Все примитивы инициализируются нулями, объекты null. Из объектов у вас тут только массив.

Как подсказали ошибка скорее всего в инициализации массива, т.к. у вас k=0 при создании объекта Plural.

Но странно, ведь по идее должен быть создан массив длинной 0, а не оставлять поле null..

---

В конструкторе вы не инициализируете массив, а создаете новый. Поменяйте конструктор на такой

```
public  Plural (){
    Array = new int[k];
}
```

Comment: Задавал значение k,ошибка как была так и осталась

Comment: @Pretty_Duck дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо  NullPointerException пропал но появилась новая ошибка)) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at Plural.funct(Inter.java:14)
 at Inter.main(Inter.java:36) тоесть выход за границы массива (похоже на то что рекурсия идет в глубь но я же задал уровень рекурсии непонятно крч)

Comment: @Pretty_Duck я в своем ответе объяснил откуда эта ошибка.

Comment: @Pretty_Duck Все зависит от 'k', вы пытаетесь обратиться к 5 элементу, которого нет. Добавьте условие if(k >= Array.length()) и пропишите ему логику, что делать если просят элемент, которого нет.